# Python script create folders from filename

Tags: python, python-2.7

Searching a python script thats move files to directions created based on the filenames.

Ex.
Filename is `ARC20180810185310.jpg`
Move that file to:
`2018>08`

---

Filename is `ARC20180910185310.jpg`
Move that file to:
`2018>09`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

It's good to try something yourself first, the ask on SO - you learn much more that way.

I would try:

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile
folder_path = '*folder path*'
os.chdir(folder_path)
for file in os.listdir(folder_path)
    year = file[3:7]
    month = file[7:9]
    final_path = folder_path + '/' + year + '>' + month + '/' + file + .jpg'
    copyfile(file, final_path)
```

Just replace the paths in ** with whatever you need.

This way you slice the file name and get year and month from it (characters from 3 to 6 and 7,8), then copyfile to a path consisting of both year and month that you sliced.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need [glob.glob()](https://kite.com/python/docs/glob.glob) function to find all files in given directory:

```
files = glob.glob('ARC*.jpg')
```

Then you will need to extract some parts of filename:

```
year = filename[3:7]
month = filename[7:9]
```

Use [os.makedirs()](https://kite.com/python/docs/os.makedirs) with exist_ok=True and create the dirs:

```
os.makedirs(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, year, month))
```

Then use [shutil.move](https://kite.com/python/docs/shutil.move) to move file to specific directory

```
shutil.move(filename, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, year, month, filename))
```

Finally you will get something like this:

```
import glob
import os.path
import shutil

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

files = glob.glob('ARC*.jpg')
for filename in files:
    year = filename[3:7]
    month = filename[7:9]
    try:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, year, month))
    except OSError:
        pass
    shutil.move(filename, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, year, month, filename))
```

Comment: have a look at `year` and `month` in the beginning of your post, seems like there's a typo and you take wrong values, like `0180` instead of `2018`. In the final version it's fine though :)

Comment: Thanks but goy a problem that in Python 2.7.xxx "exist_ok=True" not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the srcDir and dstDir, you will get your file.jpg moved, if you use MoveFile(srcDir, dstDir, resuisive=True), you will move the file.jpg in the sub-dir of the srcDir too.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os, re, shutil

class MoveFile(object):
    def __init__(self, srcDir, dstDir, recursive=False, flag='.JPG'):
        self.srcDir = srcDir
        self.dstDir = dstDir
        self.recursive = recursive
        self.flag = flag
        self.duplicateFileName = []
        self.badFileName = []
        self.jpgFile = []
        self.srcDirDict = {}

    def findAllJPG(self):
        # recursively find file 
        if self.recursive == False:        
            for item in os.listdir(self.srcDir):
                if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(self.srcDir,item)) and \
                                os.path.splitext(item)[-1] == self.flag.lower():
                    self.jpgFile.append(item)
        else:
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.srcDir):
                for item in files:
                    if os.path.splitext(item)[-1] == self.flag.lower():
                        self.jpgFile.append(item)
                        self.srcDirDict[item] = root

        if not self.jpgFile: 
            print('NOT FIND ANY JPG FILE!')
        return self.jpgFile

    def parse(self, text):
        try:
            pat =re.compile('[a-zA-Z]+([\d]+)')
            match = pat.match(text)
            data = match.group(1)
            fileName = data[:4]+'-'+data[4:6]
        except TypeError:
            self.badFileName.append(text)
            fileName = None
        return fileName  

    def move(self, text):
        try:
            fileName = self.parse(text)
            if fileName == None: return
            if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(self.dstDir, fileName)):
                os.mkdir(os.path.join(self.dstDir,fileName))

            srcPath= os.path.join(self.srcDirDict[text], text)
            dstDir = os.path.join(self.dstDir, fileName)
            shutil.move(srcPath, dstDir)
        except:
            self.duplicateFileName.append(text)
            raise

    @staticmethod
    def decC(dir):
        return os.path.join(self.srcDir,dir)

    def run(self):
        try:
            if not os.path.isdir(self.dstDir):
                os.mkdir(self.dstDir)
            for text in self.findAllJPG():
                self.move(text)
            print('MOVE SUCCESSFUL!') 
        except:
            raise

srcDir = r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\2'
dstDir = r'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\3'
fmv = MoveFile(srcDir, dstDir, recursive = False)

fmv.run()
```